# Passing empty shell variable to Java command line causes "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, bash, command-line, classpath

> java ***"$homeOption"*** -cp "$classPath" "com.civilizer.extra.tools.DataBroker" -import "$importPath"

If `$homeOption` is not empty, the command above works, but `$homeOption` is empty, it can't find the main class

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Looks like Empty `$homeOption` parameter affects `classpath` string in a bad way; It's so strange behavior to me;

Anyone running into this issue and understanding why?

Edit:

#### In case that it works:

The actual command line is as follows;

com.civilizer.extra.tools.DataBroker is a Java class with main method, and it is included in that verbose classpath;

in this case, $homeOption is **-Dcivilizer.private_home_path=/Users/bsw/.civilizer**

java **-Dcivilizer.private_home_path=/Users/bsw/.civilizer** -cp **/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/target/civilizer-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/extra/lib/*:/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/target/civilizer-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/*:/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/target/extra** com.civilizer.extra.tools.DataBroker -import

#### In case that it can't find the main class:

java -cp **/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/target/civilizer-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes:/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/extra/lib/*:/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/target/civilizer-1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/*:/Users/bsw/test/trysomething/civilizer/target/extra** com.civilizer.extra.tools.DataBroker -import

As I mentioned, only $homeOption is empty; but it just makes the issue; BTW, even if $homeOption is empty, the class will run without a problem, but you know, the main method is missing in the first place in this case, it doesn't matter

Comment: BTW, it was tested on OS X Bash

Comment: IS `DataBroker` the class with the `main` method? If not, what is the name of the class that has the `main` method. What is the value set in `homeOption` when it is not empty. Please share all relevant information that will help you to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @CKing  sorry... I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resolve this by populating an array and passing that to the java command instead.

```
opts=( )
if [[ -n "$homeOption" ]]; then
    opts+=( "$homeOption" )
fi

java "${opts[@]}" -cp "$classPath" "com.civilizer.extra.tools.DataBroker" -import "$importPath"
```

The issue you are seeing is because bash is passing a blank string to java as the first argument, and java is taking the blank string to be the class:

compare:

```
$ java foo
Error: Could not find or load main class foo
```

vs:

```
$ java ''
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

You can see that java prints the class name it can't find in the error, but your case, and my second case above, the class name is an empty string, so the class name is blank in the error message as well.

The reason my solution works is if the array is empty then bash won't pass in any empty arguments. And the array is created empty, and left empty unless $homeOption has a non-empty string.

Comment: Thanks, looks perfect!